# How to design decision after decision (diamond) in UML?

Tags: uml

I am designing UML Activity diagram in ArgoUML now.
I know that if I want to design condition like:

```
if(condition) {
    doTrueAction();
} else {
    doFalseAction();
}
```

It could be done in UML activity diagram like following:
[image]
But what if we have another condition inside the output of the previous decision? Like this:

```
if(condition) {
    if(condition2) {
        condition2TrueAction();
    } else {
        condition2FalseAction();
    }
}else{
    conditionFalseAction();
}
```

[image]

As you see conditionTrueOutput is being output and condition at the same time here. It seems to me that design is broken. 
**Edit:** Or I should use fork element instead of decision (diamond) element?

[image]

I want to know how to design this correctly. Is there any rule?

Comment: The fork is used to mark the activities as parallel ones, that is not your case. Anyway, one or more join have to follow a fork.

Comment: @acornagl Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a wrong assumption in your thoughts. A `Decision` has no output. It just has conditional control flows leaving it. Each can be guarded by a certain condition. This guard is written in square braces:

[image]

Note that I did not write the (implicit) `[true]` guard after the first test (rather by sloppiness when editing, but actually it can be omitted).

**Edit** My first though that your diagram has another flaw in that the actions have no control flow going out was incorrect. Actually Superstructures state that a missing outgoing control flow is equivalent to an `FlowFinal` after processing the `Action`. So your diagram is correct here.

Regarding your edit: as the comment says, this is for parallel continuation. Nested conditions need to be like shown above.

**Edit2** As Ister noted in the comments, a `Decision` can have more than just the `if` and `else` control flow going out, but an arbitrary number greater than 1. The UML 2.5 states on p. 388:

> If exactly one target of an unblocked outgoing edge accepts the token, then the token traverses the corresponding edge and all other offers are withdrawn. If multiple targets accept the token simultaneously, then the token traverses only one of the edges corresponding to the accepting targets, but which one is not determined by this specification.
>
> In order to avoid non-deterministic behavior, the modeler should arrange that at most one guard evaluate to true for each incoming token. If it can be ensured that only one guard will evaluate to true, a conforming implementation is not required to evaluate the guards on all outgoing edges once one has been found to evaluate to true.
>
> For use only with DecisionNodes, a predefined guard “else” (represented as an Expression with “else” as its operator and no operands) may be used for at most one outgoing edge. This guard evaluates to true only if the token is not accepted by any other outgoing edge from the DecisionNode.

Comment: @pyramidPeak : Thomas is right, but one thing is incorrect in his diagram. The conditions should not be placed as a label near the diamond, but between square brackets along the control flows. One flow has [condition] and the other has [condition = false]. Alternatively, the condition may be placed inside the diamond and the guard expressions near the control flows would then be [=true] and [=false] (note the equals sign).  See UML 2.5 spec, figures 14.25 for examples.

Comment: @Thomas: it is _not_ necessary to use an `ActivityFinalNode`. From the UML 2.5 spec: "The execution of an Activity with no streaming Parameters completes when it has no nodes executing and no nodes
enabled for execution, *or* when it is explicitly terminated using an ActivityFinalNode."

Comment: @JimL. Thanks for this. Probably I got used to using the `Final` to make it explicit. Will update the answer.

Comment: Another related common misconception is that an `InitialNode` is required. In most cases it is superfluous. An action that has no incoming edges can start executing as soon as the containing activity activates.

Comment: @JimL. But it makes it visually more clear where to start. So I would not leave it out (probably like I would never leave out the final for clarity). Is there also a passage in Superstructures that elaborates on this implicit start like it does with missing finals?

Comment: There is no "superstructures" anymore, since UML 2.5. I don't know if it's called out explicitly or not in UML 2.5. I think it is called out in fUML, which clarifies the UML semantics. fUML has test cases that ensure this works properly.

Comment: Regarding your edit, a missing outgoing control flow would be equivalent to a `FlowFinal`, not an `ActivityFinal`, because no other `Activity` is killed. When nothing more can be executed, the containing `Activity` terminates. You only need an `ActivityFinal` to kill other `Activity`s.

Comment: @JimL. Thanks again for the flow-flaw. I'm often too sloppy :-[ You are also right regarding Superstructures. 2.0 had this name the last time. But I got so used to it that I still kept it (until now).

Comment: @ThomasKilian. The answer was clear enough and correct for me. Although you think that there was flow-flaw.

Comment: Just one more remark. In UML decision nodes can have many outgoing flows, so you may have a single diamond with 3 outgoing flows with guards: `[not condition]`, `[condition and not condition2]`, `[else]`. Note that else is executed if no other guard calculates to true.

Comment: @Ister Thanks for the update. I made an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems  that your design is coherent but it is not a UML diagram. I suppose that you are mixing the **activity diagram** with the **sequence diagram**.

Your diagram looks like a sequence diagram but it tries to represent information that are related to the activity diagrams.

I suggest you this [web site](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/) to investigate on the differences between the two diagrams, I hope it can help you.

Instead, by trying to use your design, what I suggest you is to insert another *condition* (e.g. SecondConditionAction) before the two condotion2.